# How are you creating models based on Firebase documents?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious.  I come from a traditional relational database background.

So every document has an Id.  Is that Id needed to get that document back quickly, or is searching by a text field as efficient?

```
export abstract class FireBaseDoc {
  id: string = ``;
}

export class NameModel extends FireBaseDoc {
  first: string = ``;
  last: string = ``;
  email: string = ``;
}
```

I'm thinking in this case, I would create an index on email and search for a user that way since that's a unique field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every document has an Id. Is that Id needed to get that document back quickly, or is searching by a text field as efficient?

The document ID is essentially a primary key like `id` field most SQL database examples. You cannot create multiple document with duplicate ID in same collection. If you know the document ID, it's easy to get a single document as shown below:

```
await db.collection("[col_id]").doc("[doc_id]").get()
```

If you want to fetch a document by a field's value, then you would require a query:

```
await db.collection("[col_id]").where("field", "==", "value").get();

// Equivalent to:
// SELECT * FROM col WHERE field == "value";
```

If you are using any authentication service like Firebase Authentication, I would recommend using user's auth UID as document ID as its relatively easier to fetch a single document by ID instead of using a query and write security rules.

> I would create an index on email and search for a user that way since that's a unique field.

Firestore does not support any `UNIQUE INDEX` feature. Only way to ensure unique value for a field in document is to first to manually check if the value is used already or use it as the document ID.

Checkout [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://youtu.be/v_hR4K4auoQ) series for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank You.  I'm down the right path, I'll have to figure out the authentication since there are two different user types.  I'll check out your link, I appreciate the quick reply.